# Prototype for PowerSeller::PowerSeller does not match any in class

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm still fairly new to inheritance and polymorphism, so forgive me. I'm writing a group of derived classes using Scite editor in Linux, and am receiving a compile error stating that my value constructor implementation doesn't match the prototype in the header file.

**powerseller.cpp:9:1: error: prototype for \u2018PowerSeller::PowerSeller(std::string, std::string, std::string, std::string, std::string, std::string, std::string, std::string, std::string, std::string)\u2019 does not match any in class \u2018PowerSeller\u2019
powerseller.h:15:3: error: candidates are: PowerSeller::PowerSeller(const PowerSeller&)
powerseller.h:13:3: error:                 PowerSeller::PowerSeller(std::string, std::string)
powerseller.cpp:7:1: error:                 PowerSeller::PowerSeller()**

Here's my header file. The value constructor is the one throwing the error.

```
#include "seller.h"
#ifndef POWERSELLER_H
#define POWERSELLER_H

using namespace std;

class PowerSeller : public Seller
{
public:
    //constructors  & destructors
    PowerSeller();

    PowerSeller(string fName, string lName, string id, string email, string loc, string date, string numOfStars, string numOfItems, string webAddress, string yearItems);

    PowerSeller(const PowerSeller& other);

    ~PowerSeller();

    //member functions

    void setWebsite(string webAddress);

    void setYearItems(string yearItems);

    virtual void print();

    virtual void read();

    //overloaded operators

    bool operator ==(const PowerSeller& rhs);

    PowerSeller & operator =(const PowerSeller& rhs);

    //overloaded ostream

    friend ostream & operator <<(ostream& os, const PowerSeller& rhs);

protected:
    string website, items;
};
#endif
```

Here's the implementation

```
include "powerseller.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


PowerSeller::PowerSeller(){}

PowerSeller::PowerSeller(string fName, string lName, string id, string email, string loc, string date, string numOfStars, string numOfItems, string webAddress, string yearItems): Seller(fName, lName, id, email, loc, date, numOfStars, numOfItems){
    website = webAddress;
    items = yearItems;
}

PowerSeller::PowerSeller(const PowerSeller& other):Seller(other){
    website= other.website;
    items = other.items;
}

PowerSeller::~PowerSeller(){
    website = "  ";
    items = "  ";
}
```

My ultimate question is: Why is the compiler still showing that PowerSeller's value constructor only accepts two string arguments when I've altered it in the file to match the implementation?

Comment: It will be useful to provide the header for `Seller` itself as well.

Comment: This is unrelated to your question, but the destructor for `PowerSeller` also doesn't look right. In general, if you have a class member variable like `std::string website, items;` then the default destructor will call the proper destructor for `std::string`.

Comment: Did you try a complete recompile?

Comment: Just checking.. there is a missing "#" at the beginning of the cpp file... is it just a typo here?

Comment: Looks OK, are you sure you have saved the header file?

Comment: @Pedrom The missing '#' is a typo here, it's in the implementation.

@πάνταῥεῖ I've tried multiple recompiles

@EyasSH `Seller` compiles and runs correctly, so I'm not sure why you need the header for it. 

@tomse Positive.

Comment: Are you sure you are compiling the code you think you are?  often one accidently edits code from one location and accidently compiles code in a different...

Comment: Try to put a typo somewhere in your header file and check if you get a syntax error - otherwise you definitely use a different file...

Comment: I highly recommend using newlines, such as one after each parameter in the constructor and the initialization list.  Newlines and spaces don't affect the execution time of your program, but make the program more readable and easier to debug and understand.

Comment: Also, pass all your strings as "const std::string &", constant reference.  This will prevent the compiler from generating code to waste time copying all those strings.